How to sort an array of age ranges with both numbers and characters?
I have an array of strings that represent age ranges:
$AgeRanges = ( 
"<1",
"1-4",
"5-9",
"10-14",
"15-19",
"20-24",
"25-29",
"30-34",
"35-39",
"40-44",
"45-49",
"50+"
)

And if I sort them with Sort-Object I will get:
$AgeRanges | Sort-Object
<1
10-14
1-4
15-19
20-24
25-29
30-34
35-39
40-44
45-49
50+
5-9

After trying to split the strings and then convert them to integers and sort them that way and then reconstituting them with the string characters and converting them back to strings, I gave up and just hard coded the list into my script. But I have other such list that deal with children and babies.
Is there any elegant way to handle this type of problem that I am missing? Prompt the user to supply the age ranges? Shuffle the array around in fixed manner?

Sorry crew, I should have added that this (and other) AgeRange(s) come out of an API, so for those who suggested a solution to generate a sorted range from scratch, thank you, but I needed it sorted.  I think Mathias and sirtao have what I needed though.  Thanks so much!

You can pass a calculated property expression to Sort-Object and have it sort based on some derived value - like the first set of digits!
$AgeRanges |Sort-Object {$_-notlike'<*'},{($_-replace '^.*?(\d+).*$','$1') -as [int]}

The first expression will sort the input into 2 groups - those starting with < go before the rest - this ensures the lower open range (<1) always goes first.
The regex pattern ^.*?(\d+).*$ will match the entire string, capturing the first consecutive sequence of digits ((\d+)), and then replacing the whole thing with just that - ie. <1 becomes 1, 15-19 becomes 15, etc.
The conversion to [int] will force Sort-Object to sort by ordinal numeric value rather than alphabetical, so you get 5-9 before 45-49 and so on.

on 7.4 it returns 1-4 before <1 though. EDIT: if in the original array <1 comes after 1-4

you can if ($_ -eq '<1') { return 0 }; ($_-replace .... for 7.4

Thanks guys, ended up doing a first-level sort on < instead :)

UPDATE:
I finally found a regex working no problem on both Desktop and Core!
Just note this will fail in ordering things correctly if the end open range has the same number as the upper range of the last closed range.
Es: 45-50 and 50+. Not a problem in this specific instance.
$AgeRanges | Sort-Object {
    [int]($_ -replace '(?:^.*?)(\d+).?$', '$1')
}

OLD
there is most likely a regex that can one-line this... but I seem unable to find it working for both 5.1 and 7.x
so have this
$AgeRanges | Sort-Object { 
    switch ($_) {
        { $_.Substring(0, 1) -notmatch '\d' } {
            '0{0}' -f $_.Substring(1)
            break    
        }
        { $_.Substring(1, 1) -notmatch '\d' } {
            '0{0}' -f $_
            break
        }
        default {
            $_
        }
    }
}


The only items that need to be changed for proper lexicographical sorting are 1-4 and 5-9, adding a 0 before each digit (01-04 and 05-09) would make the collection be properly sorted so:
$AgeRanges = (
    '<1',
    '1-4',
    '5-9',
    '10-14',
    '15-19',
    '20-24',
    '25-29',
    '30-34',
    '35-39',
    '40-44',
    '45-49',
    '50+'
) | Sort-Object { Get-Random } # sort randomly for testing

$AgeRanges | Sort-Object { $_ -replace '^\d(?=-)|(?<=-)\d$', '0$0' }

See https://regex101.com/r/Xuzeaj/1 for regex details.

I would suggest you change how you create the list and use a function to create PSCustomObject objects with a sortable member:
Function New-AgeRange {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
      [int]$From,
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)]
      [int]$To = 0
   )
   [PSCustomObject]@{
      # For situations where you need to sort on one value first, and then on a second value, use this:
      #    Sortable = '{0:d5}{1:d5}' -f $From, $To
      Sortable = $From
      Display  = if ($From -eq 0) { "<$To" }elseif ($To -eq 0) { "$From+" }else { "$From-$To" }
   }
}

To populate the list, you might do something similar to this:
$AgeRanges = @()
$AgeRanges += New-AgeRange 0 1
$AgeRanges += New-AgeRange 1 4
for ($i = 5; $i -lt 50; $i += 5) {
   $AgeRanges += New-AgeRange $i ($i + 4)
}
$AgeRanges += New-AgeRange 50 0

And to get an array of properly sorted strings, you can do this:
($AgeRanges | Sort-Object -Property Sortable).Display


Which will produce this:
<1
1-4
5-9
10-14
15-19
20-24
25-29
30-34
35-39
40-44
45-49
50+


"0" padded strings will sort, like installdate the uninstall part of the registry:
echo 00-01,
01-04,
05-09,
10-14,
15-19,
20-24,
25-29,
30-34,
35-39,
40-44,
45-49,
50+ | sort

00-01
01-04
05-09
10-14
15-19
20-24
25-29
30-34
35-39
40-44
45-49
50+

